# Programmatically Delete Product Attribute Sets

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, attribute-set

Due to some shoddy code from a previous employee I have inherited a Magento 2 store with thousands of erroneous product attributes and hundreds of attribute sets.

I've been able to delete the attributes and move all the products back on to the Default attribute set, but now I'm left with hundreds of empty, unused product attribute sets that I can't find how to delete easily?

Comment: Via terminal you can run this command `catalog:product:attributes:cleanup` for removes unused product attributes.

Comment: Hint: that only cleans up values from the entity tables. It doesn not delete attributesets or attributes. The following tables are cleaned up:
  catalog_product_entity_varchar
  catalog_product_entity_text
  catalog_product_entity_decimal
  catalog_product_entity_datetime
  catalog_product_entity_int

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an attribute set using  `Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface` method `deleteById`

```
namespace {NameSpace};


class Test
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $attributeSetRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository
    )
    {
        $this->a

ttributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        }
        public function deleteAttributeSet()
        {
            $attributeSetId = 15;
            $this->attributeSetRepository->deleteById($attributeSetId);
        }
    }
```

### Via Object manager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $attributeSetRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
        $attributeSetRepository->deleteById($attributeSetId);
```

Comment: "The default attribute set can't be deleted" error is displayed